# iReport "keep group together" does not work in some cases

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have following problem.
I have subreport_1, now irrelevant and then subreport_2, with group header and group footer, with keepTogether = True.
Then I put subreport_1 and subreport_2 in mainReport and execute.
In some occurences, when end of subreport2 is near the end of the page, keepTogether does not work and last row is splitted, with rest, group header and footer on next page.
It works when I change size of bottom margin in mainReport, but I think it can occure again  when I have any other row count or so...
Could you help me ? 
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Which report has the keep together set? What bands are the subreports in? Maybe add a picture with what you want it to be like, and what you are getting to better illustrate the problem you are having. As of now it is difficult to tell what your definition of works is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your question posted as an answer to one of my questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830635/ireport-place-border-around-entire-group-in-column) and then noticed you had created a question of your own.  To solve this issue I grouped on the field I wanted to keep together and then in the XML view I added:

```
keepTogether="true"
```

to the group definition.  It ended up looking like:

```
<group name="group_foobar" keepTogether="true>
```

In my report this made it so that a group would not break across pages.  In the case where a group could start on a page but not completely fit then it would not print on that page and instead start on the next page.

You say you have used the keepTogether tag in your report.  Was that in subreport_2 where the grouping is actually taking place?  That's where it would need to be.  And since you are performing this grouping in a dynamically expanding subreport, I would set subreport_2 to ignore pagination and set my dimensions in the main report so that the main report can control the pagination.

Comment: Yes, keepTogether is in subreport2.
example:
Group header 1
A
B
C
Group Header 2
D
E
F

In result there is 
GroupHeader1
A
--- end of page
GroupHeader1
B
C
GroupHeader2
D
E
F
I think, when KeepTogether is true, first group should not split and all should be prínted on next page.